# Install all dependencies

Tags: chicken-scheme

As I'm developing my module (r7rs "library"), I want to be able to list my dependencies (everything that needs to be installed by `chicken-install`) in some kind of file, and do something like `chicken-install .`  Like in python: `pip install` or Clojure `lein deps`.  Is there anything like this in Chicken Scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help in the #chicken IRC channel.

It seems that the answer is to

- create an egg definition which contains the dependencies
- install the egg with `chicken-install` while in the directory of the definition.  This will install all the listed dependencies along with your egg.
- Then, to run in the interpreter, you can load the main scheme file.

https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggs%20tutorial

tool that helps creating the egg definition:  http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/chicken-belt#chicken-hatch